# Creating and setting clusters values to a new raster- k-mean classification

Tags: r, classification, gis, k-means, raster

I want to create a simple kmeans unsupervised classification. I have a problem with creating clusters and setting the cluster values to a new raster. I was inspired on this [site](https://rspatial.org/raster/rs/4-unsupclassification.html).

```
landsat5 <- stack('5.tif')
names(landsat5) <- c('blue', 'green', 'red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'thermal', 'SWIR2')
ndvi <- (landsat5[['NIR']] - landsat5[['red']]) / (landsat5[['NIR']] + landsat5[['red']])
nr <- getValues(ndvi)
set.seed(99)
kmncluster <- kmeans(na.omit(nr), centers = 10, iter.max = 500, nstart = 5, algorithm="Lloyd")
knr <- setValues(ndvi, kmncluster$cluster)
knr <- raster(ndvi)
values(knr) <- kmncluster$cluster
mycolor <- c("#fef65b","#ff0000", "#daa520","#0000ff","#0000ff","#00ff00","#cbbeb5",
             "#c3ff5b", "#ff7373", "#00ff00", "#808080")
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(ndvi, col = rev(terrain.colors(10)), main = 'Landsat-NDVI')
plot(knr, main = 'Unsupervised classification', col = mycolor )
```

I get this error :

> *Error in 'setValues(ndvi, kmncluster$cluster)':   length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1*.

Any ideas why it shows the error?

Comment: To me it seems hard to find the problem, without having any data, however: the only thing I can see, looking at your code, is the `na.omit(nr)` in `kmeans()`: does it removes some lines, so you have the number of assigned cluster (`kmncluster$cluster`) < of the number of `ndvi`?

Comment: Yes, it removes lines with NA and then the length of **nr** is the same as **kmcluster**...my mistake because i thought it is different. So now i have no idea what makes this mistake. I can link picture of my area tomorrow for better visualisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As s_t points out, the problem is created by `na.omit(nr)` because that removes cases such that the number of cases is no longer equal to the number of raster cells.

Here is a minimal, reproducible, self-contained example

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
vi <- (b$red - b$green) / (b$red + b$green)
nr <- getValues(vi)
```

There are `NA` values in `nr` (where `red+green == 0`) and these need to be removed to be able to use `kmeans`. But instead of using `na.omit` you can do

```
i <- !is.na(nr)
set.seed(99)
kmncluster <- kmeans(nr[i], centers = 10, iter.max = 500, nstart = 5, algorithm="Lloyd")
```

And now you can replace the values in `nr` with their cluster memberships and put these values into a RasterLayer

```
nr[i] <- kmncluster$cluster
knr <- setValues(vi, nr)
plot(knr)
```